# Display aggregate Keys and Values in hadoop result

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce

I am very new to Hadoop.I have written a MapReduce Program which parses an input file and extracts a specific pattern as key along with its value.
I can easily reduce it and the final output is a file with pair of keys and values.

```
public class EReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>     
{

    private Text outputKey1 = new Text();
    private Text outputValue1 = new Text();


    public void reduce(Text equipKey1, Iterator<Text> equipValues1,
                    OutputCollector<Text, Text> results1, Reporter reporter1) throws IOException {
            String output1 = "";
  while(equipValues1.hasNext())
            {
                    Text equi= equipValues1.next();
                    output1 = output1 + equi.toString();
            }

                    outputKey1.set(equipKey1.toString());
                    outputValue1.set(output1);
                    results1.collect(outputKey1, outputValue1);
}
```

The problem is, at the start of the file i need to show Total number of keys and Total number of values for a particular key as an aggregate.

Key: Date

Value: Happenings.

something like

```
12/03/2013 CMB ate pizza
           He went to a mall
           He met his friend
```

There were totally 3 happenings on the date 12/03/2013.
Like there will be set of dates and happenings.

Finally i should show,there were "This number of action" on the date "date".
there were 3 action on the date 12/03/2013
etc....

How can i achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.!

Comment: I'm on the move so can't provide details ATM, but you might want to check http://www.slideshare.net/zhengwenshen/20130201-mapreduce-design-patterns from slide 53 on (partitioning/binning pattern).

Comment: Thanks for ur help. If you find something don't forget to help me. Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this the direct answer, but I would not store aggregates along with output. Consider Pig to get aggregates. It fits well for this use case.

Also, I did not understand the "start of file" question. A reducer task could have more than one key - values to work with so your file "part-r-00000" would like

```
12/01/2012 something something1 something2 
12/02/2012 abc abc1 abc2
```

But I would lean towards storing just data emitted from reducer without aggregating it and using pig to run trough them to get the count you need (you would have to implement your udf to parse your events, which is every simple)

just a possible snippet

```
a = LOAD '/path/to/mroutput' as (dt:chararray, evdata:chararray);
b = foreach a generate dt, com.something.EVParser(evdata) as numberofevents;
c = store b into '/path/to/aggregateddata';
```